# How to configure RabbitMQ with LDAP for AD Groups?

Tags: rabbitmq, ldap

I had managed to configure RabbitMQ with LDAP and authenticate it, if it is for an individual AD account. I am using the following configurations:

RabbitMQ Config file:

```
auth_backends,[{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal},rabbit_auth_backend_internal]
```

In RabbitMQ management, I had manually created a username with no password set (it works). But, lets say I have an AD Group (called "Rabbit User Group") that has 3 users inside (User1, User2, User3).

The location of the "Rabbit User Group" is in:

`sample.companyname.com > City Name (OU) > Groups (OU) > IT Groups (OU) > "Rabbit User Group" (Security Group)`

How should I configure it in RabbitMQ management and also for the config file so that, once I update the particular group, all members inside the group will be able to authenticate and have the same permissions (e.g. only this group has admin rights) in RabbitMQ?

I want to avoid needing to manually create each individual user in the RabbitMQ management for authentication?.

I had added the following into my RabbitMQ config file

```
{
    tag_queries, [
                    {administrator,{in_group,'CN="Rabbit User Group",OU="City Name", OU=Groups, OU="IT Group",DC=sample,DC=companyname,DC=com',"uniqueMember"}},
                    {management,    {constant, true}}
                 ]
}
```

and tried creating a username called "Rabbit User Group" into the RabbitMQ management without a password. But when I tried to login as "User1", I am unable to log in.

This is my overall config file:

```
[
 {
  rabbit,
  [
   {
     auth_backends,[{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal},rabbit_auth_backend_internal]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
   rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
   [   
        {servers, ["sample.companyname.com","192.168.63.123"]},
        {dn_lookup_attribute, "userPrincipalName"},
        {dn_lookup_base, "DC=AS,DC=companyname,DC=com"},
        {user_dn_pattern, "${username}@as.companyname.com"},
        {use_ssl, false},
        {port, 636},   
        {log, true},
        {
            tag_queries, [
                            {administrator,{in_group,'CN="Rabbit User Group",OU="City Name", OU=Groups, OU="IT Group",DC=sample,DC=companyname,DC=com',"uniqueMember"}},
                            {management,    {constant, true}}
                         ]
        }
    ]%% rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
 }
].
```

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ldap.html - turn on the `network_unsafe` log level to see what is happening. This may help as well - https://github.com/MarcialRosales/rabbitmq-ldap-integration

Comment: @LukeBakken Thank you for the reply and also for the links. I appreciate it. Yep I had been referring to the  github.com/MarcialRosales/rabbitmq-ldap-integration  for the in_group. But it did not work for me. After several trial and error I finally found the method to make it work. I will share the answer below , incase someone encounters the same issue as me.  And also thank you for the hints to use the "network_unsafe", I will try it out =)

Comment: @LukeBakken , if you don't mind , I would like to ask if there is a way for me to allow users to log in using their email address / "userPrincipalName" instead of using the "cn" ? the following solution that I had posted below will require the user to enter their name according to the User CN name in the Microsoft Active Directory to login instead of using their accountName.  My CN for the user is called "Snow Bunny" but my userPrincipalName is "snow.bunny@domain.com" and the  sAMAccountName is "snow.bunny"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the "dn_lookup_attribute" to distinguishedName (DN) instead of the userPrincipalName / sAMAccountName so that it will use this user's DN for member checking in the in_group. As shown below:

```
{dn_lookup_attribute, "distinguishedName"}, 
{user_dn_pattern, "CN=${username},OU=Users,DC=sample,DC=companyname,DC=com"},
```

Instead of:

```
{dn_lookup_attribute, "userPrincipalName"},
{user_dn_pattern, "${username}@as.companyname.com"},
```

Microsoft Active Directory and OpenLDAP are different LDAP service flavors and have different user list attribute for groups. The Microsoft Active Directory Group for the users list is called "member" while the OpenLDAP group is called "uniqueMember".

**Overall config file:**

```
[
 {
  rabbit,
  [
   {
     auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal]  
   }
  ]
 },
 {
   rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
   [   
        {servers, ["sample.companyname.com","192.168.63.123"]},

        {dn_lookup_attribute, "distinguishedName"},
        {dn_lookup_base, "DC=AS,DC=companyname,DC=com"},
        {user_dn_pattern, "CN=${username},OU=Users,DC=sample,DC=companyname,DC=com"},
        
        {use_ssl, false},
        {port, 636},   
        {log, true},
        {
            tag_queries, [
                            {administrator,{in_group,"CN=Rabbit User Group,OU=City Name, OU=Groups, OU=IT Group,DC=sample,DC=companyname,DC=com","member"}},
                            {management,    {constant, true}}
                         ]
        }
    ]%% rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
 }
].
```